# Ruby conditional statements

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

How do I express multiple or options in a conditional statement in Ruby?  I thought something like this would work but it doesn't:

```
1 == (3 || 2 || 1)
(1 == (3 || 2 || 1))
```

I thought those would return true.

I want a way to say if any number of a group of things are true then return true. Do I have to spell it out the long way?

```
if (1 == 3 || 1 == 2 || 1 == 1)
```

In English I would say it

> If 1 equals 3, 2, or 1, then return true.

Comment: Maybe something like [3,2,1].include?(1)

Comment: I want it to be exactly equal to.

Comment: .include? returns true if one of the object == anObject, it is as exact as your example could be.

Comment: What if I changed to Strings "dog", "dog toys", "big dog toys".  And my string that I was comparing it to was "big dog".  In my scenario I would want it to return false, but I think it would return true.

Comment: No, it wouldn't return true.

Comment: A `1` is always a `1` so `1 == 1`. A string that is exactly the same will match, `'a'` == `'a'`, but substrings will not match, even if they're found, `'foo' != 'foobar'`.

Comment: I'm not aware of any language that allows `1 == (3 || 2 || 1)`. You can do something slightly similar in a regex pattern, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's one way to do it. More Rubyesque would be:

```
if [3, 2, 1].include?(1)
```

The reason that `1 == (3 || 2 || 1)` doesn't work is because `(3 || 2 || 1)` is evaluated first. The `||` operator returns the first value if it's truthy, and the second if the first is falsy.

Thus `(3 || 2 || 1)` is `3`, so you're comparing `1 == 3`, which is obviously `false`.

Comment: Actually, `3 || 2 || 1` returns `3`, not `true` - the resulting comparison is `1 == 3` which is even more obviously false!

Comment: Wow, wonder how I got 4 upvotes and a green check with such a glaring error. Fixed now.

Comment: I'm going to be *really* pedantic now - `||` is defined so that `falsy || anything` returns `anything`. So `false || nil` returns `nil`, while `nil || false` returns `false` :)

Comment: Egads, I was too hasty again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `include` method does what you want. Also, you could use the `any?` methods that pretty well expresses what you want:

```
[1, 2, 3].any? { |v| 1 == v }
```

But for equality you can just use `include`.

Answer (score 1):

If your values to test against are not contiguous, then the `Array#include?` is a good choice.

If the test values are continguous, and can be expressed as a [Range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html), you could use:

```
Range#cover?
Range#include?
Range#member?
```

For example:

```
(1..3).member?(1) # => true
```

`include?` and `member?` are perhaps a bit more generic, defined in [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html), and so applicable to any collection object, or class derived from there. Enumerable also defines `any?`, used in another answer to this question, plus `none?`  and `one?`.

Comment: I tend to use `(1..3) === 1`, rather than `(1..3).member?(1)`, but that's how I roll.

Answer (score 0):

The `case when` conditional supports multiple options:

```
x = 1
puts case x
  when 1, 2, 3 then "Low"
  when 4, 5, 6 then "High"
  else "Strange dice..."
end
#=>Low
```